# Backup a table using pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have a database name employee (id , name, address , Phonenumber , salary). I would like to make a backup of the employee details if anyone of Phno,addres and salary is changed.
Is there any way of doing it using pg_dump or I should be satisfied with trigger method that output original Tuples onto another Table say Backup if any changes are made .

Please , if someone could elaborate in detailed manner how to get start with this using pg_dump.

Answer (score 2):

`pg_dump` scripts out the current state of the database. That's all it does, with some fine-tuning to let you get at individual tables, schemas, etc. It does not watch for changes, it does not work at the row level (barring some zany row-level security setup), and it is not an audit log.

What you're describing -- backing up individual rows when they're modified -- *is* an audit log, so `pg_dump` is the wrong tool for the job. An update trigger which inserts the original row into an audit table is the canonical way to accomplish this, so you're on the right track there. If you need to generate scripts of the audit table, *that's* where `pg_dump` comes in.